# How do i get the taxonomy term name on the CPT archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

In archive-news.php, i've tried

```
global $wp_query;

$tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
echo $tax->name;
```

But this gets the taxonomy, not the taxonomy term.

I need to print the tax term name for each entry on the archive page which lists posts in the custom post type.

Answer (score -1):

[wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) did the trick

Comment: Use `get_the_terms()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/#user-contributed-notes